# Is it possible to use Lerna for multiple typescript projects that use rxjs (for example) on api boundaries?

Tags: typescript, npm, rxjs, lerna

I am trying to get 2 existing npm projects that are currently in separate repos working in a mono repo using lerna.

Project A depends on Project B and they are both typescript projects. Project B exposes functions that return an observable, Project A uses the observables from these functions.

As the node_modules of Project A are sym-linked to Project B Project A can see 2 different rxjs folders. It's own installed in it's own node_modules folder and an identical version installed in Project B's node_modules.
Because of these 2 copies of rxjs I get errors similar to:

Type import("package_A_node_modules/rxjs").Observable is not assignable to type import("package_B_node_modules/rxjs").Observable.

The recommended approach to this is to move dependencies to the root project. In theory this is great and it mostly works. You don't get any duplicated dependencies but there are some things that break:

1. if a package has no dependencies when it's installed into a consuming app none of it's dependencies will be installed!
2. some packages need to be installed at the child project level.
3. If a child project has peer dependencies defined there is no warning that the dependencies installed at the root project are compatible with the peers listed for the child project

An example of number 2 is that when trying to run an angular aot build it complains that `@angular/cli` cannot be found in `ProjectA/node_modules/angular`. Angular cli depends on rxjs so when I install it at the child project level I get another rxjs copy and the problem returns.
There is a similar problem with concurrently. It needs to be installed in the child project and again it depends on rxjs.

At the moment I can't see any way around this and it seems that this approach won't work.